# Working with Hibernate Queries

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am new to hibernate queries, and trying to get a grasp on how everything works. I am using Hibernate 3 with Netbeans 6.5.

I have a basic project set up and have been playing around with how to do everything. I started with essentially a search query. Where the user can enter values into one or more fields.

The table would be Person with the columns first_name, middle_name, last_name for the sake of the example.

The first way I found was to have a method that took firstName, middleName, and lastName as parameters:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
String query = "from Person where (first_name = :firstName or :firstName is null) "+
               "and (middle_name = :middleName or :middleName is null) "
               "and (last_name = :lastname or :lastName is null)";
Query q = session.createQuery(query);
q.setString("firstName", firstName);
q.setString("middleName", middleName);
q.setString("lastName", lastName);
List<Person> results = (List<Person>) q.list();
```

This did not sit well with me, since it seemed like I should not have to write that much, and well, that I was doing it wrong. So I kept digging and found another way:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
if (firstName != null) {
     crit.add(Expression.eq("firstName", firstName);
}
if (middleName != null) {
     crit.add(Expression.eq("middleName", middleName);
}
if (lastName != null) {
     crit.add(Expression.eq("lastName", lastName);
}
List<Person> results = (List<Person>) crit.list();
```

**So what I am trying to figure out is which way is the preferred way for this type of query? Criteria or Query? Why?**

I am guessing that Criteria is the preferred way and you should only use Query when you need to write it by hand for performance type reasons. Am I close?

Comment: Just a note, your Expression.ge should probably be Expression.eq

Comment: Thanks. I would say it was a typo, but that would be a lie. I was wondering want 'ge' stood for. All kinds of stuff in there. Thanks again.

Comment: "ge" stands for "greater than or equal".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Criteria is the preferred way. It uses Prepared Statements in the background, so you don't need to worry about SQL injection.

Comment: That makes since. Appreciate the input. So would my last statement to use Query for performance reasons be accurate?

Comment: @jschoen I believe hibernate will create an optimal query for you when you use Criteria, so performance should not be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Criteria is the newer way.  It was introduced after the hql query layer.  Underneath the Criteria api still generates hql.  I tend to use the Criteria api because the code looks cleaner and its easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought it did, just was not sure since most information out there is about writing HQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its very common to write queries, specially when you want to make complex inquires, Hibernate has its own query language.

Check [Hibernate Query Language HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Answer (score 1):

Criteria is the best way to make dynamic queries. No need for null checks on a parameter, just don't add that criteria.